# How to trim every element of a list that is loaded from application.yaml using SPEL expression

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application that has the following in one of the service. I have list of strings separated by comma inside applicaiton.yaml file, I need to load this list into an array list and trim each and every element using Spring SPEL expression.

```
@Value("#{'${fruit.list}'.split(',')}") 
private List<String> myList;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

```
    @Value("#{'${fruit.list}'.replaceAll('\\s+', '').split(',')}")
    List<String> myList;
```